# SQLiteLog no such table

Tags: sqlite, android

Android Studio + SQLite 3.
Есть готовая база. Скопировал файл в папку:
\src\main\res\assests\

Базу проектировал с помощью SQlite Expert Pro.
При попытке получить данные, приложение закрывается, вот текст ошибки:
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: tclients

Таблица "tclients" точно есть в базе.

Вот код DB.java:

```
package com.mkt.app;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
public class DB {

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "clients.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String TABLE_TCLIENTS = "tclients";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIO = "fio";

    private final Context mCtx;

    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        Log.v("DBPATH1", DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }


    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        Log.v("DBPATH2", DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        checkDataBase();
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
    }

    // получить все данные из таблицы TCLIENTS
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_TCLIENTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    // добавить запись в TCLIENTS
    public void addRec(String name, String fio) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FIO, fio);
        mDB.insert(TABLE_TCLIENTS, null, cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(TABLE_TCLIENTS, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }


    // класс по созданию и управлению БД
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

//            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
//            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
//                cv.put(COLUMN_FIO, "sometext " + i);
//                cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//                db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте сырым запросом её достать, может получится.

Comment: public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.rawQuery("select * from tclients", null);
    }



Всё равно no such table: tclients

Вопрос в том, нужно ли каким-то специальным способом копировать файл базы из assets в рабочую папку? Или копирование файла базы выполняется самим установщиком при инсталляции apk?

Comment: вот это ключевой факт. Так как Вы самостоятельно ничего не копируете, то и базы там скорее всего нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что база-то физически есть

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }


из logcat
01-07 15:57:59.376    1642-1642/com.mkt.app V/dbFile﹕ /data/data/com.mkt.app/databases/clients.db   true

Comment: Вы проверили наличие файла. А является ли данный файл базой... кто его знает. Выведите хотя бы размер и сравните с тем, что добавили в проект.

Comment: Получается, что андроид САМ, без моего ведома создаёт базу?
Я только что переименовал файл базы в папке assets и запустил приложение, в логе:
01-07 16:44:49.237    1710-1710/com.mkt.app V/dbFile﹕ /data/data/com.mkt.app/databases/clients.db   true

вот что здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/125883/ вычитал:
SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase вызывает Context.openOrCreateDatabase

получается, что я должен скопировать сам базу из assets ДО ТОГО КАК?

Comment: почему без Вашего ведома? Вы ведь getWritableDatabase вызвали? А документацию почитали? там явно написано "Create and/or open".

Comment: я так понял, что вначале нужно вызвать метод getReadableDatabase, чтобы андроид создал пустую базу, потом вызвать метод close, а уж затем копировать свою готовую базу. Блиииин... столько рутины с этими жабами и ведроидами...

Comment: а разве нельзя сразу проверить наличие файла и если его нет - скопировать? думаю, что в других системах это точно также. И если у Вас не получается, то это не значит, что виноват андроид.